# Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to load native library:

Tags: java, android, executable

I have JRE made for Android. I am trying to execute `/data/local/tmp/j/java` but that gives
following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM Unable to load native library:
```

The other files for java are at: `/data/local/tmp/java`.

I have executed following commands:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/local/tmp/java/lib/jli
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/local/tmp/java/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/local/tmp/java/lib/server
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/local/tmp/java
```

But the same error as above is still showing. The reason why i have moved java executable to `/data/local/tmp/j/java` is because on Android you can only execute and include `lib[name].so` files in `jniLibs/abi` so i am unable to move `bin, lib` folders to `/jniLibs/abi`.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out with this as i am working for days to get this completed.